# How to allocate positive and negative numbers into separate clusters

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am working on clustering and the data has two unlabeled columns having both negative and positive numbers. What is the best way to do clustering on this data. Also is there a way where we can make sure that negative first coordinate will not be in same cluster as the positive first coordinate ?

I have tried using K means clustering . However I am not able to customise it making the positive first coordinate and negative first coordinates in separate clusters

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To separate on first coordinate by sign, you can split your dataset into those two parts and cluster them separately.